# CPU efficiency during animations

Tags: ios, swift, performance, cpu, clock

Using Swift5.2, iOS13.4,

I try to animate an analog clock with second-, minute- and hour hands.

The full example of the Clock can be found here: [Link](Here is the full example that I am using : [Example Clock](https://github.com/afil310/Clocket)

Everything works - except that my iPhone heats up due to poor CPU efficiency in my angle calculations or angle-animation.

I've found that the below angle-animations are responsible for the iPhone warming up.

How can I improve my code so that it is more CPU efficient ?

Here is the angle calculation code:

```
public struct LocalTime {
    var hour: Double = 10.0
    var minute: Double = 10.0
    var second: Int = 25
}

let translateToRadian: CGFloat = CGFloat(Double.pi/180.0)
```

The following is calculated every 1 Second inside a Timer-tick:

```
secondHand.updateHandAngle(angle: CGFloat(localTime.second * 6) * translateToRadian, duration: 1.0, options: .curveLinear)
minuteHand.updateHandAngle(angle: CGFloat(localTime.minute * 6) * translateToRadian, duration: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut)
hourHand.updateHandAngle(angle: CGFloat(localTime.hour * 30) * translateToRadian, duration: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut)
```

Here is the updateAngle method:

```
func updateHandAngle(angle: CGFloat, duration: Double, options: UIView.AnimationOptions) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                          delay: 0.0,
                        options: options,
                     animations: { self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle) },
                     completion: { (finished: Bool) in return }
    )
}
```

Comment: Show `updateHandAngle`. It is _very_ unlikely that the code you did show is actually responsible for any kind of CPU warmup.

Comment: You are right, the animation is the problem (I changed my original post accordingly). But how can I improve it ?

Comment: Try to profile your program with Xcode

Comment: I’d suggest profiling (see [Getting Started with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/)). If the CPU is getting crushed, then, try simplifying the implementation and seeing how that affects the behavior (e.g. try without animating, just changing `transform`; if you have shadows or alpha, try without shadows and no alpha; try without updating the UI, but just print statements, and see if the issue is just the re-awakening the CPU every second). But until you’ve done diagnostics to narrow down the specific problem, we can’t help.

Comment: But I did a quick test with a single sweeping `UIImageView` second hand on iPhone 10 Xs Max, and it’s not appreciably warm. So, you need to provide a [reproducible example of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), after, of course, you’ve done the aforementioned diagnostics to narrow down the issue...

Comment: There are 3 UIImageView's that represent the 3 clock hands (sec, min, hr). Each UIImageView has an image that contains transparent parts. Therefore I cannot leave out alpha as suggested by Rob. What do I have to do in order to animate images with transparency in it ?

Comment: Here is the full example that I am using : [Example Clock](https://github.com/afil310/Clocket). It also shows the heating problem. In my code, I only changed the hands to be a UIImageView but the heating up is identical from the full example code that I refer from. What could be changed in order to stop the heating problem ?

Comment: “Therefore I cannot leave out alpha as suggested by Rob.” ... I’m not suggesting leaving it out in the end app. I’m advising that you temporarily try simplifying your app, piece-by-piece, to perform root-cause analysis. Then, once you’ve identified the key contributor(s) of the problem, then you figure out how to address it. But until you do this root-cause analysis to diagnose the problem, you’re flying blind.

Comment: ah ok, I understand. The root cause is identified: it is the UIView.animate(...). If I change my hand-images to non-transparent, and in addition, if I only show the second-hand, then the GPU-usage drops from 100% to 90%. But it still makes up for most.  Every second, there is a UIView.animate(...) call that rotates for a duration of 1sec. What can I do to improve ??

Comment: Any idea ? I am soooo desperate at this - no idea why a simple UIView.animate(...) causes such a heat problem. I am on it since 5 hours. The 3 hands are UIImageViews and are added as subviews. Please see the [original example](https://github.com/afil310/Clocket) that heats up as well - no idea why ????

Comment: You can try to rotate layers instead of views. Transformation of CALayer is CPU efficient because it mostly processed by GPU.

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, do you have an example of such a CALayer rotation ? How do I rotate a UIImageView during 1sec every second with this?

Comment: @iKK If you need to rotate with stepping - just setup repeating timer with 1 sec. If you need smooth rotation during 1 minute - set timer with 1 tick per min, and add animation with duration. Here is example how to rotate layer: arrowLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: angle))

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, I try that now.

Comment: I tried: same thing !  100% device-uitilization with `arrowLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: angle))` (inside UIView.animate(withDuration: ...). Please have a look at the [original example](https://github.com/afil310/Clocket)

Comment: Please have a look at the [original example](https://github.com/afil310/Clocket). Inside Pods-->Clocket-->ClockHand you find the `updateHandAngle` method that heats up ! Why ??   (...no matter what I exchange the UIView.animate method's rotation with, it heats up. Is it because I use 3 subviews and they all rotate in parallel ?  I tried storyboard and also non-storyboard - no change. I tried to leave out two of the three views - no change. It all comes to the UIView.animate method where things go wrong. Does anybody have a analog-Clock (with 3 hands) example that might work better ??

Comment: I finally found a solution: I kicked out the original solution and replace it by:  [this analog Clock implementation](https://github.com/fnoah/AnalogClock). Now it is working without any heating up !   Thanks to all of you that tried to help !!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "minute" and "hour" return an integer, it seems the minute hand only changes every minute, and the hour hand only every hour. So animate the hands to a new position only when it is needed, and one third of the CPU usage is gone.

Alternatively, if you moved the minutes hand every second by a little amount, any animation would be invisible. (Look at the minutes hand of a mechanical watch. It moves but you can't see it moving). So you wouldn't need animation at all, and think about how often you want to update the hour.

Comment: Thank you, it all makes sense. However, I completely eliminated hour and minute hand and still, the original UIView.animate would heat.  Therefore I think your input helps in general. But in the above case with the [original example](https://github.com/afil310/Clocket), it wouldn't make a difference. Of course, I could set the second-animation just once (instead of every second). But to align with system-clock I thought of updating the animation every second (for the duration of 1 sec) which does make things complicated.